# microsoft jscript runtime error "8001A38F"

Tags: javascript, java, runtime-error

i have a problem in execution of jscript when i try to open it it always throws a error
" microsoft jscript runtime error" "800A138F"
i format my pc upgraded to win 10 to win 11 still same error unable to run jscript files

i tried reset my pc
upgraded windows

Comment: Please edit your grammar and punctuation to let StackOverflow provide quality content

Comment: this is javascript